# Change packet IPv4 address into IPv6 address and play the packet into the network card

Tags: c#, packet

I am using `PcapDotNet` DLLs in my application, take `Wireshark` file and play the packet over my network card.
Now what i want to do is take change the packet `IPv4` address to `IPv6` packet.

so i parse paccket into `byte[]` using this DLLs and convert into string HEXA:

```
string hexa = "0030881545830018e7fdaea1080045000034021f40008006e616C0A80001cab11079c29c0077a0804bc8f98dd24e501840fc82b6000041525449434c452033340d0a";
```

This is my `IPv4` address (192.168.0.1):

```
C0A80001
```

And this is the IPv6 address after converted from `IPv4`:

```
fe80:0:0:0:0:0:c0a8:1
```

And in `Hexa`:

```
66-65-38-30-3A-30-3A-30-3A-30-3A-30-3A-30-3A-63-30-61-38-3A-31

public static string StirngToHexa(string str)
{
    byte[] ba = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str);
    string hexString = BitConverter.ToString(ba);
    return hexString;

}

public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                     .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                     .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                     .ToArray();
}
```

So i have replace my `IPv4` with `IPv6` (without '-'), build new packet and play this packet.
the problem is that after play this packet and check vei `Wireshark` the result, the packet IP was something strange like `58.48.58.48` and not IPv6.
Am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: The code that play the packet is here: http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Pcap.Net%20Tutorial%20-%20Sending%20Packets&referringTitle=Pcap.Net%20User%20Guide , this is works fine, my only problem is that my new packet should maybe build with other parameters ?

Comment: I mean show how you're converting it to [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_packet). There's a *a lot* more than just the IP address that is different from [IPv4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4).

Comment: I did it online: http://www.subnetonline.com/pages/subnet-calculators/ipv4-to-ipv6-converter.php

Comment: I don't think you understand. Look at those links to IPv4 and IPv6. There's more to the header than just the IP address, that it doesn't sound like you're changing (*like the version field!*)  There are other fields, and you'll need to move the IP payload, because an IPv6 header is larger than IPv4. All you're doing is manipulating the *address*, not the *header*. (In fact, you're probably trashing the rest of the IPv4 header).

Comment: If what I stated sounds like nonsense to you, you should really go through some introduction to TCP/IP networking tutorials, or get a book that covers the topic.